# Is it possible with Sanity? scheduled external API calls to Sanity

Tags: sanity

Here is what I would like to accomplish?

1- Make a fetch call to a news API everynight
2- Pull latest headlines
3- Import to Sanity...

Does Sanity let you do that? Does it have a cron job?

Thank you,

Answer (score 3):

Sanity does not provide any native way to do that, but you could create cron jobs with an external serverless provider that does the functionality you're looking for

[Firebase scheduled functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions) are an example of provider, but there are many more options. I suggest taking a look at [Serverless framework examples](https://www.serverless.com/examples/).

After you figure out what you'll use, then use [Sanity's HTTP API](https://www.sanity.io/docs/http-api) or [one of their API clients](https://www.sanity.io/plugins?category=library) (`@sanity/client` for Javascript) to add the data to it. You'll need a token to do so, as POST requests are protected behind an auth wall (take a look at their [Authentication docs](https://www.sanity.io/docs/http-auth)).

Here's an example of what that could look like in Javascript:

```js
// For Javascript - using the @sanity/client npm package
const allHeadlines = await pullHeadlines(/* ... */);

// Create a single transaction that will handle
// the creation of all headline documents
const transaction = sanityClient.transaction();
for (const headline of allHeadlines) {
  transaction = transaction.create({ title: headline.title, ...headline });
}

transaction
  .commit()
  .then((res) => {
    console.log("All headlines created");
    // Finish the cron job here
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error("Couldn't create the headline documents", error);
    // Maybe retry it here?
  });
```

Hope that helps, Timur

Comment: Can you please take a look at the following question:https://stackoverflow.com/q/66902726/9409877