# Unable to add code blocks in Sanity CMS after I install the code-input plugin

Tags: reactjs, content-management-system, sanity, headless-cms

I am learning to build a blog using Sanity CMS and React. I am new to Sanity.

I should be able to insert code snippets in my blog posts. So, I have installed the `code-input` plugin.

According to the [link](https://www.sanity.io/plugins/code-input) here, after I install the plugin I have to use the following code in my schema types.
[image]
I have no idea where do I insert the code.

Please help.

My folder structure is as follows:

[image]

sanityblog/blockContent.js

```
/**
 * This is the schema definition for the rich text fields used for
 * for this blog studio. When you import it in schemas.js it can be
 * reused in other parts of the studio with:
 *  {
 *    name: 'someName',
 *    title: 'Some title',
 *    type: 'blockContent'
 *  }
 */
export default {
  title: "Block Content",
  name: "blockContent",
  type: "array",
  of: [
    {
      title: "Block",
      type: "block",
      // Styles let you set what your user can mark up blocks with. These
      // correspond with HTML tags, but you can set any title or value
      // you want and decide how you want to deal with it where you want to
      // use your content.
      styles: [
        { title: "Normal", value: "normal" },
        { title: "H1", value: "h1" },
        { title: "H2", value: "h2" },
        { title: "H3", value: "h3" },
        { title: "H4", value: "h4" },
        { title: "Quote", value: "blockquote" },
      ],
      lists: [{ title: "Bullet", value: "bullet" }],
      // Marks let you mark up inline text in the block editor.
      marks: {
        // Decorators usually describe a single property – e.g. a typographic
        // preference or highlighting by editors.
        decorators: [
          { title: "Strong", value: "strong" },
          { title: "Emphasis", value: "em" },
        ],
        // Annotations can be any object structure – e.g. a link or a footnote.
        annotations: [
          {
            title: "URL",
            name: "link",
            type: "object",
            fields: [
              {
                title: "URL",
                name: "href",
                type: "url",
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
    },
    // You can add additional types here. Note that you can't use
    // primitive types such as 'string' and 'number' in the same array
    // as a block type.
    {
      type: "image",
      options: { hotspot: true },
    },
  ],
};
```

sanityblog/schema.js

```
// First, we must import the schema creator
import createSchema from "part:@sanity/base/schema-creator";

// Then import schema types from any plugins that might expose them
import schemaTypes from "all:part:@sanity/base/schema-type";

// We import object and document schemas
import blockContent from "./blockContent";
import category from "./category";
import post from "./post";
import author from "./author";

// Then we give our schema to the builder and provide the result to Sanity
export default createSchema({
  // We name our schema
  name: "default",
  // Then proceed to concatenate our document type
  // to the ones provided by any plugins that are installed
  types: schemaTypes.concat([
    // The following are document types which will appear
    // in the studio.
    post,
    author,
    category,
    // When added to this list, object types can be used as
    // { type: 'typename' } in other document schemas
    blockContent,
  ]),
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you installed the plugin correctly, it's now available as a schema type to be used in any of your other schemas. So, to answer your question, **you can put that code anywhere you want code blocks in your Sanity studio**. I'd strongly suggest going over the [content modelling](https://www.sanity.io/docs/content-modelling) documentation

Specifically to your question, assuming you use the `sanityBlog/blockContent.js` field for the content of your posts, you can add it there. Here's how that would look like:

```
export default {
  title: "Block Content",
  name: "blockContent",
  type: "array",
  of: [
    {
      title: "Block",
      type: "block",
      // ...annotations, styles, lists and marks you already have
    },
    {
      type: "image",
      options: { hotspot: true },
    },
    // Add the code block here 
    // it'll show up as one of the blocks available in your
    // Portable Text Editor
    {
      type: "code",
      title: "Code block",
    }
  ],
};
```

For specifics on the portable text / rich content field (`type: "block"`), refer to the [block type documentation](https://www.sanity.io/docs/block-type). If you want to take it one step back, refer to the [general block content documentation](https://www.sanity.io/docs/block-content).

Hope this helps

Comment: Can you please take a look at the following question:https://stackoverflow.com/q/66943323/9409877

Comment: I'd like to stress that the guide tells you to install the plugin via Sanity. In other words to install it with `sanity install @sanity/code-input`. If you install it with npm or yarn, you also need to remember to add `@sanity/code-input` to the plugins array in `sanity.json`.